# Unix sed command to find and replace a pattern

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

I am trying to match the below pattern which has spaces in between.

```
         -DsomeArg=some value
```

and to replace it with below pattern using sed command.

```
         -DsomeArg="some value"
```

There can be any number of spaces in between. I tried below command but it's not working.

```
          sed 's/^\(-D.*\)=(.\+\s\+.\+)/\1="\2"/' test.dat
```

where as .* works instead of .+ , but I want to match one or more pattern. I am not able to find what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What is the end of the value? End of line?

Comment: What's wrong with `sed 's/\(-D.*=\)\(.*\)/\1"\2"/'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat /tmp/test | sed -r 's/^(-D.*?)=(.+\s+.+)/\1="\2"/'
-DsomeArg="some value"
```

Hope that will help :)

Answer (score 0):

This does what you asked for:

```
sed 's/=\(.*\)/="\1"/'
```

or a little shorter:

```
sed 's/=/="/;s/$/"/'
```

But I have a feeling there's more to the story than you're saying. Like, are you expecting some text to follow "some value" that you want to leave outside of the quotation marks? Does something precede `-DsomeArg` that you don't want to match?

With regular expressions, context is everything.